# Format-Specifiers Syntax Error?

Tags: printf, format-specifiers

i am having a little trouble with printf specifiers...so before asking you guys i read almost everything on[C++Reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), but couldnt fix the problem, and since i am new at c i cant even understand the problem, its most likely a syntax error but i can't find it...

```
for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {  
    printf("\n%d.%s%n",i,names[i-1],offset);
    printf("%*s%.2f TL",10-offset," ",prices[i-1]);
}
```

so basically i have this code to print a list, and i want the prices to start from the same column. 
For e.g:

1. water    1.00
2. oj       1.00

and the logic behind my code (incase it's not obvious, i can't tell if it is) is:

- print id number and name, count how many chars we've written so far and assign it to offset.
- print (starting column of price list)-offset spaces before price

once i couldn't get the result i want, i checked and found out that offset is 3 for all names which is not the case(and no value is assigned to offset before this procedure).

Thanks for any kind of help !

PS: This is a practice code just to get better at using specifiers efficiently.

edit:
so i did this :

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
```

{

```
printf("%d.%s%n",i,names[i-1],&offset);
printf("%*s%.2f TL\n",10-offset," ",prices[i-1]);
```

}

but what i get as a result is huge empty black command screen.

Comment: printf is C, the preferred construct is `cout << ...;` in C++.

Comment: i'm confused, yes im working on c but since there is a c++ reference guide on c++ reference page, i thought it would be ok to ask it here

Comment: @user3402183 sure is. printf is perfectly valid C++. It's in the standard header <cstdio>, cf. 27.9.2 of the standard draft.

Comment: URW. Btw, I didn't know about %* and had forgotten about %n. Learnt something :-)

Comment: Well, a huge black command screen... so we are at stage 4 of the software development process (doesn't compile -- compiles but doesn't link -- compiles, links, but crashes -- compiles, links, runs, but doesn't do what I want). Your code prints just fine (and tabulated!) when I run it, so the reason for the huge black screen is now somewhere else. Try printing something static first thing in main... print some debug output in the loop... stuff like that.

Comment: lets clarify a couple of things: when i compile and run i get no errors but i get a huge black cmd screen(pretty sure its not standart, something makes it print " " everywhere)which is not what i suppose to get, and at the and of that screen , it prints the last line which is 0.75 TL

Comment: BTW (prices[10]= 0.75)... and screen is huge only vertically , it doesn't print anything that exceeds prob 100 char horizontally..=/

Comment: i just tried to print offset value after prices[10] it printed 32763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The %n format specifier requires a pointer. Your code is missing the & operator for offset:

```
printf("\n%d.%s%n",i,names[i-1],&offset);
```

The good ol' C interface doesn't know what types you supply to printf so it doesn't complain and happily reads the 4 byte integer value of offset on the stack as a memory location -> core dump.

Actually, g++ with -Wall **does** warn. So

- hd1 has a point here because C++ output is type safe (even though it's a pain);
- Heed thy warnings.

Comment: Appearantly i cannot answer my own questions, so to inform you that i have tried the solution and still failed, i leave this comment.(edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%n` in a `printf` format, the corresponding parameter must be a pointer. `printf` will store the information in the `int` you point it to.

Assuming you've declared `int offset` somewhere, you should use `&offset` as the last argument in your `printf` call.

While we're here, allow me to comment on this excerpt:

```
printf("\n
```

ARGH NO! Newline is a *terminator*. It goes at the end of a line, not the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the info, and i fixed it immediately! ^^

Answer (score 0):

so i did this :

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
```

{

```
printf("%d.%s%n",i,names[i-1],&offset);
printf("%*s%.2f TL\n",10-offset," ",prices[i-1]);
```

}

but what i get as a result is huge empty black command screen.

edit: Can you guys try this and tell me if you get normal results? I can't understand the mistake occuring, so i can't get past it...Maybe some other examples will lead me to where is the mistake.